# Is 4c + 0 equal to #4c4c4c?

Tags: colors

If not, what color is it?
My client asked me to use '4c + 0' for color. From what I have learned from Google, it seems to be the color #4c4c4c. Is that correct?

Comment: i don't have enough information regarding you client question, but i could assume that you client means 4/0 full color front blank back.

Answer (score 0):

The color `4c` is just an abreviation for the color `4c4c4c`. The `+0` doesn't change anything.